# JPA one-to-many relationship question (relations on one entity)

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

In [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/Relationsononeentity.htm) JPA example there is a code:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Deity mother;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Deity father;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Deity> children;
```

Why relation with father and mother is implemented by *@OneToOne* annotation and not in *@ManyToOne* relation? If *Child* and *Parent* will be separate classes *Parent* will have `@OneToMany Collection<Child> children` and *Child* have `@ManyToOne Parent parent`. This (deity) example seems reasonable but I looking for explanation why is that.

Links to JPA specification will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right, it is supposed to be **ManyToOne** relationship.

It must have been a mistake from the author of this code.
Other parts of the code look suspicious also, I wouldn't trust it too much...

---

If you are looking for good persistence examples, I suggest the Hibernate documentation.
Hibernate sticks with JPA as much as possible.

> Note: You could switch your code to Hibernate, or stay with what you use and only use their documentation...

Comment: Well, it is example from OpenJPA - http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openjpa/tags/1.2.0/openjpa-examples/src/main/java/relations/ . So this example is bad to or this is relations on one entity special case.

Comment: @cetnar Are you asking a question?

Comment: If this example is wrong, my question is invalid, but if it is correct I'm looking for explanation why is that.

Comment: @cetnar OK, I understand :-) **I believe the OneToOne example is wrong**, and also other parts of the example seem questionable, so I answered this way. You can trust this opinion or not, it is up to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but the example in site could refer to a person who has 1 mother and 1 father(hence unique one to one relation) and many children (one to many relation).

This example might be just to show that relations.

PS: i really am not sure, but then this is what occured to me..